# Perl - Inconsistent output

Tags: regex, perl

This is the code that is matching users and their home storage capacity, the strange thing is that it yields the same result five times, instead of five unique results as it's meant to.

```
open( my $storage_input, "du -shc /home/*|" );

while ( my $line3 = <$storage_input> ) {
    push( @user_storage, $line3 );
}

foreach my $line3 ( @user_storage ) {
    if ( $line3 =~ m/^([0-9](.){1,})M\s+\/[a-z]{1,4}\/([a-z]{4}|[a-z]{1}\d{2}[a-z]{5})/ ) {
        %storage = ( "data" => "$1", "user" => "$3", );
        push( @storage_data, \%storage );
    }

}

print "\n";

foreach ( my $i = 0 ; $i < scalar( @storage_data ) ; $i++ ) {
    print $storage_data[$i]{"user"};
    print " has used ";
    print $storage_data[$i]{"data"};
    print " MiB of storage.\n";
}
```

This is the command output that we are matching:

```
3.4M    /home/jony  
3.4M    /home/luha  
40M /home/maho  
35M /home/mipa  
3.0M    /home/svkn
```

Comment: What is the output of `du -shc /home/*`? And what is the output from your code?

Comment: You're pushing the same reference every time.

Comment: Try to localize a new storate instance (my %storate = ) or just do anony href `push( @storage_data, {"data" => "$1", "user" => "$3"} );`

Comment: Thank you. It did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

You push a reference to `%storage` to `@storage_data`, and then change `%storage`. You should use a different `%storage` for each iteration of the loop, i.e. prepend `my` to its assignment.

```
my %storage = (
```

Do you use `strict`?

Alternatively, you can store an anonymous hash:

```
push @storage_data, { data => "$1",
                      user => "$3",
                    };
```

Comment: Superfluous quotes around `$1` and `$3`? Although I imagine you have your reasons!

Comment: @Borodin: I prefer to quote the `$1` variables everytime, even if the context is harmless (as here). They can do weird things when used unquoted as function arguments, though.

Comment: @Borodin: e.g. http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1052659, http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1008823 ...